# Creating a buffer containing an array of structures with fields that sizes do not align to a byte

Tags: c, embedded

I'm writing a driver for TLC6C5724 in C. This driver uses a common shift register, amongst other fields, uses an array of structures containing 3 fields. Here are two examples of such structures:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t outb : 7;
    uint8_t outg : 7;
    uint8_t outr : 7;
} dcdata_field_t;
```

or

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t outb : 12;
    uint16_t outg : 12;
    uint16_t outr : 12;
} gs_field_t;
```

And then we would create an array of these as follows:

```
dcdata_field_t dcdata[8];
gs_field_t gsdata[8];
```

And the expected result would be a buffer like:

```
uint8_t dcdata_output[21];
```

Which would contain data in following manner:

```
Bits 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 ...
     |  outb[0]  |     oubg[0]      | ...
```

Do you know a good way to pack/parse an array of one of these structures into a buffer that can be used to transmit this configurations to a device using for example SPI. There must be no padding between structure or fields in the output buffer.

Comment: "There must be no padding between structure or fields in the output buffer."  --> `dcdata_field_t` will have padding as 3 `uint8_t` does not exactly fit 3*7 bits.  Likewise for `gs_field_t`, 3 `uint16_t` does not exactly fit 3*12 bits.  Step 1, allow padding between the fields.

Comment: In C, the size of any object (returned by the `sizeof` operator) is expressed as the number of *bytes*, not *bits*, that it contains. Since `sizeof` must always return an integer (specifically, a `size_t`), there's no way to create an object with a size that's not byte-aligned. So, while you can use bitfields to store the data in memory, when you transfer it you will need to avoid the padding yourself. You can't just pass the whole array blindly.

Comment: uint8_t arrayof3x7bits [N][21]; or uint8_t *arrayof3x7bits = malloc(21*N);

Answer (score 4):

> Do you know a good way to pack/parse an array of one of these structures into a buffer

Yes. Do not use bitfields. Write abstractions above normal char buffer. Uses bit shifts and bit operations on top of normal char buffer.

Your interface might look like the following:

```
struct dcdata_field_t {
   unsigned char buffer[21];
};

// enumerate fields
enum dcdata_field_e {
   dcdata_field_outb = 'b',
   dcdata_field_outg = 'g',
   dcdata_field_outr = 'r',
};

// setter
void dcdata_set(struct dcdata_field_t *t, unsigned index, enum dcdata_field_e field, unsigned char value) {
   // your logic to set proper bits of buffer.
}

// getter
unsigned char dcdata_get(const struct dcdata_field_t *t, unsigned index, enum dcdata_field_e field) {
   // your logic to get proper bits in buffer
}
```

Comment: ah we basically wrote the same conclusion. For C++ I know several packing serialization libraries, is there anything for C99 short of directly going for an ASN.1 compiler?

Comment: No. Search for them https://github.com/search?q=bitstream+language%3Ac&type=code . I would write my own code for this specific problem, sounds like real fun.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you mean something like XDR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation or protobuf: https://protobuf.dev/ ?

Comment: @CraigEstey no, Protobuf defines headers and is very restrictive on layout. think more like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1

Comment: @KamilCuk Not saying we have a different idea of fun, but: :D

Comment: @KamilCuk My problem with this whole shmack was getting data correctly put in a buffer at byte junction as there would be a problem of constantly changing offset. Any suggestion how to tackle that?

Answer (score 2):

In C, objects (aside from the bit field *within* your struct objects) *must* consist of whole bytes; C  2018 6.2.6 2:

> Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes…

(thanks to Eric Postpischil for pointing this out!)

The only way around that would be to create "super structs", e.g. one that contains the fields from 8 `dcdata_field_t`s; e.g.,

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t outb_1 : 7;
    uint8_t outg_1 : 7;
    uint8_t outr_1 : 7;
    uint8_t outb_2 : 7;
    uint8_t outg_2 : 7;
/* … */
    uint8_t outg_7 : 7;
    uint8_t outb_8 : 7;
    uint8_t outg_8 : 7;
    uint8_t outr_8 : 7;
} dcdata_field_t;
```

because the length of that would be a multiple of an octet. (And even then, there might be other things that restrict alignment, and thus make your packing impossible.)

(For your other struct, two of them would already suffice.)

Quite frankly, that is a terrible idea, and you should just write a pair of functions that extract the bitfields through shift and mask operations from larger integer types. Generally, just use 8 bit values in your CPU for your 7-bit colors up to the serialization. Then things become easier:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t r, g, b;
} color;

void serialize(color* colors, unsigned int howmany, char* buffer)
{
  n_eight = howmany / 8;
  for(unsigned int idx = 0; idx < n_eight; ++idx)
  {
    c_idx = idx * 8;
    *(buffer++) = (colors[c_idx].r << 1) | ((colors[c_idx].g & (1<<6))>>6);
    *(buffer++) = (colors[c_idx].g << 2) | ((colors[c_idx].b & (3 << 5))>>5);
  /* And so on… */
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I always though that, even though you use bitfields, it would be padded till the end you the type you're using so that's very helpful! Sorry I can't cast a vote as this is a new account but this was very helpful nonetheless